# Can I use my second monitor as my primary on tails?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, tails, linux

I have an all in one PC / desktop. It was knocked over and now has LCD lines and a ton of dead pixels on it. I can only see about half of the screen. The other monitor works fine when I'm using just Windows so its not broke. Anyways, I looked around and couldn't find a way to do such things. Does anyone know if this is possible to do on TAILS?

Comment: Does Applications > System Tools > Preferences > System Settings... then Displays have anything useful?

Comment: When i go to display It gives me little options like rotate my screen or change the resolution. I have seen some people say they have a set as primary button but I dont have it

Comment: It is not possible to be ultimately anonymous if you are to do so.

Comment: I can get the monitor to work but the mouse stays on the laptop screen.